# How to install VMware Workbench IS on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vmware-sdk

I have tried unsucessfully to install **VMware Workbench IS** 3.5.7 [3.5.7.4238219] from https://code.vmware.com/web/workbench/wbis/3.5 . I tried  (*Help* => *Install new software*) with two different versions of eclipse, having two different errors:

**1) eclipse package from Ubuntu**

I installed eclipse **package** for **Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS** (Version: **3.8.1** , Build id: debbuild) and installed latest updates. When I tried to add the repository I got this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: VMware Workbench CIM Tools 3.5.7.4236111 (com.vmware.vide.cimtools.feature.feature.group 3.5.7.4236111)
  Missing requirement: Action Plug-in 3.5.7.4236111 (com.vmware.vide.p2action 3.5.7.4236111) requires 'package org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.artifact 2.3.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Action Plug-in 3.5.7.4249275 (com.vmware.vide.p2action 3.5.7.4249275) requires 'package org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.artifact 2.3.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: VMware Workbench CIM Tools 3.5.7.4236111 (com.vmware.vide.cimtools.feature.feature.group 3.5.7.4236111)
    To: com.vmware.vide.feature.feature.group [3.5.5,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: VMware Workbench Core 3.5.7.4236111 (com.vmware.vide.feature.feature.group 3.5.7.4236111)
    To: com.vmware.vide.p2action [3.5.7.4236111]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: VMware Workbench Core 3.5.7.4249275 (com.vmware.vide.feature.feature.group 3.5.7.4249275)
    To: com.vmware.vide.p2action [3.5.7.4249275]
```

I looked for that **`package org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.artifact 2.3.0`** but I don't know how to satisfy it.

**2) Latest eclipse from eclipse.org**

I downloaded and executed the fresh **eclipse installer** for **Linux 64 bits** (again Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS). It's Version: **Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)** and Build id: 20170314-1500. Again I installed latest updates and tried to install that **VMware Workbench IS** repository and I got this error:

```
An error occurred while configuring the installed items
session context was:(profile=_home_test_eclipse_java-neon_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Configure, operand=null --> [R]com.vmware.vide.vlogbrowser.cli.feature.feature.group 3.5.7.4236111, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.ChmodAction).
The action chmod failed - file /home/test/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/features/com.vmware.vide.vlogbrowser.cli.feature_3.5.7.4236111/app/vmwb-server does not exist
```

Can anybody help me to install VMware Workbench IS?

Thanks in advance!

/Angel

Answer (score 1):

I realized that ubuntu's eclipse already provides the plugin org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository, but it's version **2.2** and VMware Workbench IS requires 2.3. I don't know if it can be installed.

Finally **I could install the workbench** on a fresh **eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)** but just after **installing the components one by one**, in a common sense order and reading carefully the errors: missing folders that the installer is not creating for you, like **`$INSTALL_PATH/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/features/com.vmware.vide.vlogbrowser.cli.feature_3.5.7.4236111/app/vmwb-server`**

Thanks and best regards

/Angel